# Apache POI Runtimeexception on close()

Tags: java, apache, exception, apache-poi, docx

I have a problem using Apache POI to read some .docx contents and show the result as unformatted preview. Im using POI version 3.11.

Code:

```
private static String POI2Text(File file) {
    POITextExtractor extractor = null;
    try {
        extractor = ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(file);
        return extractor.getText();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.warn("Error:", ex);
    } finally {
        if (extractor!=null) try { extractor.close(); } catch (Exception ex) { logger.warn("Error:", ex); }
    }
    return "";
}
```

The following Exception is thrown in the finally block (extractor.close()):

```
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.OpenXML4JRuntimeException: Fail to save: an error occurs while > saving the package : part
     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:503) ~[agent.jar:na]
     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1425) ~[agent.jar:na]
     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.save(OPCPackage.java:1412) ~[agent.jar:na]
     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.closeImpl(ZipPackage.java:353) ~[agent.jar:na]
     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.close(OPCPackage.java:425) ~[agent.jar:na]
     at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTextExtractor.close(POIXMLTextExtractor.java:87) ~[agent.jar:na]
     ....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: part
     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.addPackagePart(OPCPackage.java:873) ~[agent.jar:na]
     at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.saveImpl(ZipPackage.java:448) ~[agent.jar:na]
     ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Any ideas how to prevent this exception? The biggest problem is, that poi doesn't release the file handle after the exception is thrown. I need to be able to move or edit the file outside of my app.

Comment: Is this on all files, or just a handful?

Comment: And can you try a recent nightly build? (Newer than 3.11 final)

Comment: I will check tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. I checked today, it works with most .docx files. There are just a handful, were this error occurs. I was not able to try it with a nightly yet, i will report back if anything changed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick feedback: I could resolve the issue by opening an inputstream as read-only and then using this stream to extract data with the POITextExtractor.

```
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.READ);
            POITextExtractor extractor = ExtractorFactory.createExtractor(is)) {
    return extractor.getText();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    logger.warn("Error in file {}", path, ex);
}
```